# select li from ul : drop down box with Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html from a webpage:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" id="tgbtn" 
           class="btn btn-default" style="min-width: 110px;">Search by</button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                class="btn btn-default  dropdown-toggle">
                <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">
            <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parcel #</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PIN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Property Location</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mailing Address</a></li>
        </ul>
```

The above code forms a drop down box on the web page, through one of the **JS libraries**, but of-course it not a select `-option` dropdown box. What I need in this particular case is one line of 
javascript preferably (2nd: jquery) that will set the `'Mailing Address'` to be selected in the pseudo-drop down.

I have tried a few things with no success.
This is for web scraping of another website, which is why I'm looking for a one liner, not a function, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eq. Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

**Jquery:**

```
$('.form-group').find('.dropdown-menu').find('li').eq(4).click();
```

You can provide the index of the element you want to select to the `.eq(index)` method.

Comment: Add some clarification to your answer.

Comment: @psylogic there is no id='mail' in the supplied html and I cant edit as its someone else's webpage

Comment: I was just reviewing low quality posts, that's why I said to add clarification to your answer ;)

Comment: @dingo_d the comment was supposed to be for the OP but I tagged you by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form-group').find('.dropdown-menu').find('li').last().click();
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of why this solves the OP's problem.  Help others to understand.

Comment: @furcicim     how do I select the <li> with 'Parcel #'

Comment: Like @psylogic answer $('.form-group').find('.dropdown-menu').find('li').eq(1).click();